# Вычисление натурального и и десятичного логарифма

Tags: c++

Дана задача: реализовать функцию для вычисления натурального и десятичного логарифма. Проблема состоит в том, что я не понимаю как их перегружать, если функции обе должны вернуть double и принимать один параметр, который тоже может быть как и double, так и int. Какие отличия или свойста между этими функциями могут быть, чтоб я все таки смог их перегрузить? Функций пока толком не реализовывал. Можно, конечно, один параметр сделать int'ом. Но, мне кажется, что преподаватель не это хотел видеть.

```
double logarithm(int a){
    return log(a);
}

double logarithm(float a){
    return log10(a);
}
```

В математике не силен, прошу не кидать тапками.

Comment: А почему это обязательно должны быть перегруженные функции? Может одна функция должна возвращать кортеж из натурального и десятичного логарифма?

Comment: @maestro выполняю лабораторную работу за кого-то, там именно указано, что это должны быть перегруженные функции, такая тема у работы.

Comment: Дайте *точное* задание, а не ваше его понимание. Слово в слово, как указано преподом.

Comment: @Harry Написать функции с перегруженными идентификаторами и основную часть программы, которая их вызывает(скорее всего Main имеется ввиду). Вариант 14:  а). Для вычисления натурального логарифма. б) Для вычисления десятичного логарифма.

Абсолютно все другие варианты понятны и ясны для меня и вопросы с реализацией не возникают, а здесь именно такая ерунда.

Comment: Мне кажется, что у вас есть **два** задания. Одно - написать перегруженные функции для натурального логарифма, второе - для десятичного.

Comment: @Harry, спасибо, скорее всего, что вы правы. Могу ли я как-то отметить ваш ответ?

Comment: Да не стоит он того :)